# hadoop and java installing

Tags: java, hadoop, centos

i am trying to install java and hadoop

in Cantos

BUT
when I logging to

```
'vi .bashrc`
```

and i had enter these commands

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_51
 export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
 export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u
 export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

after that i want to check the java version by writing this command

```
$ java -version
```

this message show to me

```
bash: java: java command not found
```

what i do ???????????

help please

^_^

Comment: after more than of 10 hours , i found a way and i had installed java , now another problem in hadoop itself , there is problem in the bash

Answer (score 0):

To reflect changes made in `.bashrc` you have to logout or restart your system.

Comment: i did this but still the same

Comment: @dalyaraad did you checked that after restarting your system the changes you made are still there in `.bashrc`

Comment: @dalyaraad Please have a look at this , might be helpful. [Path Variable Setting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). Please decide what shell Centos uses.

Comment: thank you , i tried and found that i was given a path wrong , but thankfully is working now :)))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to `export` your environment variable on .bashrc, 
on second place
you have to use: `/usr/java/latest/bin` if you want to address you latest Java installation executables
third you can give a chance to your `.bashrc` after editing it or loging-off/login-in or 
`. .bashrc`
and try to 

`echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $PATH`
take a look at what `whereis javac` say you

Comment: can you please explain in details what should i do , because i am new in centos

Answer (score 0):

I did install jdk 1.6 on centos. You can try same steps for jdk 1.7 :

1)  Download JDK version 1.6.0_45 file (`jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin`) for 64 bit machine from below link :

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR
```

2)  From terminal, go to the path where you have download these files :

```
cd /path
```

3)  Change the mode of jdk bin file to executable using below cmd :

```
chmod a+x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
```

4)  Also change the mode of jre bin file to executable using below cmd :

```
chmod a+x jre-6u45-linux-x64.bin
```

5)  Execute the bin files using

```
./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
./jre-6u45-linux-x64.bin
```

This will create folders by jdk and jre names

6)  Check default java configured on your machine using command :

```
alternatives --config java
```

Select the current selected version by '+' sign.

7)  Run below command to remove the java. 
`alternatives --remove java /path` given in the config command

8)  Repeat above command until there is no output for config command. Repeat steps 7 to 10 for javac, javaws and libjavaplugin.
Now move local folders `jdk1.6.0_45` and `jre1.6.0_45` to `/usr/java` directory.

9)  Install `Sun/Oracle JDK java, javaws, libjavaplugin.so` (for Firefox/Mozilla) and javac with `alternatives –install` command :

### java

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/java 20000
```

### javaws

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/javaws 20000
```

### Java Browser (Mozilla) Plugin 32-bit

```
alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so

 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so 20000
```

### Java Browser (Mozilla) Plugin 64-bit

```
alternatives --install /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so.x86_64 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 20000
```

### Install javac only if you installed JDK (Java Development Kit) package

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac 20000

alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/jar 20000
```

10) Install `Sun/Oracle JRE java, javaws and libjavaplugin.so` (for Firefox/Mozilla) with `alternatives –install` command

### java

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jre1.6.0_45/bin/java 20000
```

### javaws

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/jre1.6.0_45/bin/javaws 20000
```

### Java Browser (Mozilla) Plugin 32-bit

```
alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so /usr/java/jre1.6.0_45/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so 20000
```

### Java Browser (Mozilla) Plugin 64-bit

```
alternatives --install /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so.x86_64 /usr/java/jre1.6.0_45/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 20000
```

11) Check current java, javac, javaws and libjavaplugin.so versions

```
java -version
javac -version
javaws
```

12) Now config following :
`alternatives --config java`   # or javac or javaws or libjavaplugin.so
There are 4 programs which provide 'java'.

```
  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java
*  3           /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/bin/java
 + 4           /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/java
Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
Note: java with [+] is currently on use.
```

13) Add `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to /etc/profile file or $`HOME/.bash_profile` file

```
## export JAVA_HOME JDK ##
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45"
## export JAVA_HOME JRE ##
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.6.0_45"
```

Comment: if you have downloaded java then follow steps 6 onwards.

Comment: thanks alot , but not work :((( , i think the problem in bashrc file itself and i dont what to do , because , bashrc do add the changes

Comment: Provide me the steps you have followed here.